# How to automatically run .sh after a file is uploaded

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, express, sails.js

I am new to Sails/nodeJS. I am trying to create a system that will automatically run a .sh after a video is uploaded to the server (local file system). I understand from [Sails documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/file-uploads) that file uploading is done in Controller file, and what I want to do is to trigger a .sh after that. I need to constantly read the output from .sh and return it to the backend.

Anyone has any idea how to implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You always can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/exec

Simple implementation:

```
var exec = require('exec');

exec('PATH TO YOUR .SH FILE', function(err, out, code) {
  // Process to the next action within the callback function.
});
```